# How do I organize all my LEGO bricks and parts?

Tags: organisation

I have a massive amount of LEGO laying around in a container. It's kind of hard to sort through whenever I need parts. I was wondering if anyone has experience with many different sizes of LEGO bricks/parts and how to organize them. This seems like a problem most LEGO enthusiasts will have at some point, so is there some kind of "best practice" for a sorting scheme? What's the most suitable container to store LEGO in? Is there a common box that enthusiasts use? Do people often make their own box?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you mentioned sorting and storing LEGO does become an issue as you start to amass a massive collection. There are however great solutions worked out already by LEGO fans. The earlier you set up a storage system that works for you, the better, and the easier it is going to be to manage your projects, and also stay enthusiastic in the hobby. Here are a couple of articles I wrote in regards to the topic, laying out what LEGO fans use and ways to get you started:

How to sort LEGO: http://thebrickblogger.com/2010/12/how-to-sort-lego/

How to store LEGO: http://thebrickblogger.com/2010/12/how-to-store-lego/

In addition, I have been maintaining a couple of Flickr Galleries where people show off their LEGO storing and sorting solutions. Seeing how other people sort and organize their LEGO can be very helpful, especially as your collection grows.

LEGO Display & Storage Ideas Gallery 2: http://www.flickr.com/photos/akunthita/galleries/72157629813455752/

LEGO Display & Storage Ideas Gallery 1:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/akunthita/galleries/72157625185890950/

You don't have to spend that much to set up a good system. What it requires though is to think through what you want and also what kind of space you have. The above information should get you started with ideas and solutions, and you should be able to get yourself organized easily.

Comment: Stack Exchange frowns on link-only answers because links may die, and that causes the answer to be useless once they do. Without clicking those links, I get close to zero information (aside from the fact that the information does, or did, exist) from this answer. Strongly recommend summarizing each of the links you offer, so in a worst-case-scenario there is still *something* useful here.

Comment: @KRyan but if "The BrickBlogger" loses interest in its blog, it is unlikely to care about this answer. So why would it bother working to make this answer useful in that case?

Comment: @Mσᶎ Uh, cuz maybe he cares about this community and making it the best of can be?

Comment: @KRyan right now that's possibly true (its pattern of link-only answers suggests otherwise, however). My point was that your request is future-oriented, "in the future if you lose interest in your blog the links will become useless", but in that even they'll also likely lose interest in this site. The willingness to spam links into duplicate questions is also bad.

Comment: I appreciate the concern, however I would add that sorting and storing LEGO is a dynamic process - besides just the basic separate by colors and/or parts. There is no absolute answer that will forever pass the test of time. And there are always newer and better storage solutions becoming available. This is why I added a link to two galleries I curate on flickr featuring solutions people come up with. I felt that this was more useful than just saying "you should sort this way". Yes, one day flickr, TBB and even this site may disappear, and we will all die, but the answer is relevant for now.

Comment: In addition, the OP selected this as the best answer, which means that they found it helpful for their purposes. Isn't this is what this forum supposed to be about? Helping each other out instead of just being an encyclopedia of dry information?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people prefer wide, shallow boxes to store parts — because it allows you more surface area to see what's in there. A Dollar store is a great place to get cheap storage containers.

Answer (score 3):

Sorting LEGO bricks is more complex than you might think. Frequency of use, shape of the brick, and communication with others are essential features of a good classification. Have a look at this book, it covers the sorting of LEGO bricks extensively: [The Ideal Order](http://www.minifigure.org/book/the-ideal-order/)

Answer (score 2):

Well if you need to organize your collection in a neat way that is easy to get to, I would use tackle boxes that you would normally use for fishing, because they come in all sorts of sizes and shapes and it can be easy to organize your collection in a neat way.